# How to define istio annotation to exclude local reference

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Is there a way to define `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges`
only to my localhost (not 127.0.0.1, but local ip of pod like "10.2.2.2") which means that all output to my local ip will be ignored?

Thanks

Comment: will it be better to work on kubernetes `network policy` more than in Istio for this case?

Comment: In istio there are [Authorization policies](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization-policies) which can affect service mesh services and secure them with rules. What is Your goal? Is it for multi cluster purposes?

Comment: Hi, I have services which uses the hostname of the pod. I wanted istio to treat it as if I used 127.0.0.1